# C#/CIL: type of native int

Tags: c#, cil

I am writing some tools to help validate IL that is emitted at runtime. A part of this validation involves maintaining a `Stack<Type>` as OpCodes are emitted so that future OpCodes that utilize these stack elements can be validated as using the proper types. I am confused as to how to handle the `ldind.i` opcode, however.

The Microsoft documentation states:

> The ldind.i instruction indirectly loads a native int value from the
>   specified address (of type native int, &, or *) onto the stack as a
>   native int.

In C#, native int is not defined, and I am confused as to what type most accurately represents this data. How can I determine what its size is, and which C# type should be used to represent it? I am concerned it will vary by system hardware.

Comment: a: there isn't one, and b: yes it could depend on hardware *and* runtime (x86/x64 etc); btw - you might find [Sigil](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Sigil/) (also [here](https://github.com/kevin-montrose/Sigil)) to be everything you're looking for, but already built and tested

Comment: It is IntPtr in C#. What's "native" about it is that it size changes depending on the process bitness, 4 bytes in 32-bit mode and 8 bytes in 64-bit mode. Makes it capable of storing a pointer.  Getting ldind.i from a C# program requires the *fixed* keyword to access an IntPtr[] array through a pointer.  Which is unsafe code that is not verifiable, no bounds check.

Comment: So, just to clarify then, `ldind.i` is essentially de-referencing a native pointer that points to a native pointer? E.g. the address on the stack is an `IntPtr**`?

Comment: No, IntPtr*.  IntPtr foo[] = new IntPtr[1]; fixed (IntPtr* p = &foo[0]) { var value = *p; }

Comment: Easier:  IntPtr* p = null;  var v = *p;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To my mind, you'd be better off looking at how the VES is defined and using a dedicated enum to model the types on the stack rather than C# visible types. Otherwise you're in for a rude surprise when we get to the floating point type.

From MS Partition I.pdf<sup>1</sup>, Section 12.1:

> The CLI model uses an evaluation stack [...] However, the CLI supports only a subset of these types in its operations upon values stored on its evaluation stack—`int32`, `int64`, and `native int`. In addition, the CLI supports an *internal data type to represent floating-point values* on the internal evaluation stack. The size of the internal data type is implementation-dependent.

So those, as well as things like references are the things you should track, and I'd recommend you do that with an explicit model of the VES Stack using *its* terms.

---

<sup>1</sup>[ECMA C# and Common Language Infrastructure Standards](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/license-terms/ecma-c-common-language-infrastructure-standards/)